# Is there any way to create an array with two different values?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create an associative array (Key, Value) without using Collections.

I saw many HashTable functions over the internet but what I found was something like a random index assignment for a single value at time with modular operations.

What I want to do is something like a bidimensional array with integer keys and string values allocating random index with % operations for each key.

I know I can do this with Collections and HashTable objects, but I want to do it by my own.

Comment: Please post what you have tried till now?

Comment: What is the use of allocating `random index`?

Comment: By `random_index` I mean he is talking about `hashCode`

Comment: Guess you should check out the working of a `HashMap` that may give you an idea of how you can do of your own

Comment: abhijeet I have nothing to show, it's just a question before creating something.

Comment: I think that all I can do is create an Array of Objects, by that way It could be possible to insert any kind of Object to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 arrays. one array to store keys while the other array to store values. And you can make sure that in your MyHashMap class you implement your methods in a way that both arrays get updated when one is updated.

Comment: Seems legit, two arrays each one of one dimension updated at time by one funcion. The problem is searching on it.

Answer (score 0):

No java has no associate arrays without using Collections. I suggest you to use a string array `Strings[][]` and in your logic convert the `string` to an `integer` for a `key`.

> But using`Collections Interface` is very easy and very efficient.

Comment: That was other option a bidimensional array for instance String[3][1] and then Integer.parseInt(valueToAddToArray) for String "numbers"

Comment: Yeah that was what I said